# How should I attribute free images?

Tags: discussion, images, policy, attribution

When I wrote [this answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2376/59), I didn't want to confuse people with what type of paper clip I was discussing, so I hit up Google for free pictures.

I figured that, to keep site rules, as well as just plain being fair, I should link to the site where I got that image from. I went poking around that site, just be sure that it was okay with *them* that I was using their image, and when I found that it was, I linked to their Terms and Conditions page as well.

One user commented on that answer, thanking me for teaching him how to link to free images. All right, whatever, the blind leading the lame and all that.

**What do I need to do on SE when I "borrow" someone else's free images?**

- Provide a link to the source?
- Provide a link to the source and their T&C?
- Something more, something less? Something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think by definition following the terms and conditions listed in "Terms & Conditions" should suffice, without the need to link to that page. It seems that in your case you were interested in acting above possible suspicion of misuse, in which case it didn't hurt to include that link as well.

**Update:**

"Official" SO convention appears to set a lower bar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

I can't see the rules being substantially different for other SEs or for images as opposed to text.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'd like to know if there is an official SE policy somewhere, that I haven't seen.

Comment: FWIW, that referencing page is in every help section on all SEs. Answer accepted.